# Changing password for connected Marketing cloud user

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, passwords

After Changing the password for connected Marketing cloud user I seem to have some issues - I'm not seeing individual email results.

Is there anything that I need to update in the Marketing Cloud when I update the password in Salesforce?

Comment: Did you make sure to mark all the tracking check boxes in the marketing cloud Tab

Comment: In the Journey I chose to send tacking data back to Salesforce. There still seems to be something that's not working with Individual Email Results.

Comment: Not in the journey but you need to mark all the checkboxes in the salesforce marketing cloud tab as well

Comment: I reconnected the user with the specified Marketing cloud User I had set up which resolved the issue. There was nothing specific that seemed to cause the  IER to stop syncing across.